# Magento 2.2.5 Show product name in product id coumn

Tags: grid, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I have created the admin grid using layout blocks **not using UI Component**.

In that, I have a `product_id` column. I want to show the `product_name` in that column.

Here is my code:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="product_id">
 <arguments>
   <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</argument>
   <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
   <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
   <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
   <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom renderer just like you used when creating grid using blocks. To do so,

Change:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="product_id">
 <arguments>
   <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</argument>
   <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
   <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
   <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
   <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="product_id">
 <arguments>
   <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</argument>
   <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
   <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
   <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
   <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
   <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\ProductName.php</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

then create a new renderer file **ProductName.php** at the path **[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Renderer** and write code like below:

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer;
class ProductName extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, array $data = array()) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        if($row->getId() != '') {
            /**
            * Write your custom logic to 
            * get product name from product ID
            * and assign it in a variable like $productName
            */
            return $productName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it just render the data alone or it will work on the filter and sort

Comment: I have tried it with a single table. It works for filters and sorting. Not tried with a join table.

Comment: I am having the product id in single custom table. Is it possible to sort it based on product name?

Comment: But you will join other table to get the product name. Am I right?